# Ajax error when wrapping data in form

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am new to using Ajax and am trying to receive data submitted in a form using the following code.

```
<div>

    <p> <label for="name">Full Name:</label>    
    <input type="text" name="name" required/></p>
    <br />

    <p><label for="email">Email:</label>    
    <input type="text" name="email" required/></p>
    <br />

    <p><label for="id">id:</label>  
    <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo($id); ?>" required/></p>
    <br />

    <p><label for="phone">Phone:</label>    
    <input type="text" name="phone" /></p>
    <br />

    <p><label for="phone">Message:</label>  
    <textarea required></textarea></p>

    <button onclick="myCall()" type="submit">Submit</button>
    <div id="mybox">
        Answer: 
    </div>

</div>
```

The jQuery

```
<script>

    function myCall() {
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "processor.php",
            type: "GET",            
            dataType: "html"
        });

        request.done(function(msg) {
            $("#mybox").html(msg);          
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    }
</script>
```

And this works fine when just echoing a test message, however the form data is not sent as it obviously needs wrapping in a form tag, when I do this I get the following error come up.

```
Request failed: error
```

The HTML with the form tag:

```
<form class="claim" method="get" id="contact">
          <div>

         <p> <label for="name">Full Name:</label>   
            <input type="text" name="name" required/></p>
            <br />

          <p><label for="email">Email:</label>  
            <input type="text" name="email" required/></p>
            <br />

            <p><label for="id">id:</label>  
            <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo($id); ?>" required/></p>
            <br />

            <p><label for="phone">Phone:</label>    
            <input type="text" name="phone" /></p>
            <br />

            <p><label for="phone">Message:</label>  
            <textarea required></textarea></p>

            <button onclick="myCall()" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <div id="mybox">
             Answer: 
        </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

And then the page reloads, submitting the form - am I missing something here?

I am sure this is a simple thing to do, we all have to start somewhere! Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing the data in with your request. Add your form tag back in and serialize it in your call, like this:

```
function myCall() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "processor.php",
        type: "GET",      
        data: $("#contact").serialize(),      
        dataType: "html"
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I am still getting the same error message and then the form submits and takes me to the php script...

Comment: Comment out the JavaScript (or disable JavaScript in your browser). Does it work then?

Comment: Yes it works in a sense of submitting the form, the php script currently just echo's the ID from the submitted form.

Comment: Does your form work with `action="processor.php"`? I'd also remove the dataType property, it probably is not necessary.

Comment: Yes the form works with that on a standard submit, its just with the Ajax it brings up the error, I removed the Type which gave the same result.

Comment: Also when the form tag is not in place and the processor.php script just echoes a test message, this seems to work just fine, its just passing the data to it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37458/discussion-between-andy-gaskell-and-james-leist)